# curl request to AWS lambda function receives no json

Tags: go, curl, aws-lambda

I have code copied directly from the go section of the lambda tutorial

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

type MyEvent struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age  int    `json:"age"`
}

type MyResponse struct {
    Message string `json:"Answer"`
}

func HandleLambdaEvent(ctx context.Context, event MyEvent) (MyResponse, error) {
    // event
    eventJson, _ := json.MarshalIndent(event, "", "  ")
    log.Printf("EVENT: %s", eventJson)

    return MyResponse{Message: fmt.Sprintf("%s is %d years old!", event.Name, event.Age)}, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(HandleLambdaEvent)
}
```

I have created a .zip file, a role, attached that role and created the function on lambda.
I can invoke the function with aws lambda successfully

```
# aws lambda invoke --function-name my-function --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out --payload '{"name": "Kevin", "age":62}' output.txt

# cat output.txt
{"Answer":"Kevin is 62 years old!"}
```

I created a function URL and can call it via awscurl (or curl)

```
# curl -X POST https://XXXXXXXXXX.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws/  \
    -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
    --user AWS_ID:AWS_KEY \
    --aws-sigv4 "aws:amz:us-east-1:lambda \
    -d '{"Name": "Kevin", "Age": 62}'
```

But the json doesn't go to the function (verified from the logs) and so isn't processed by **my-function**

```
{"Answer":" is 0 years old!"}
```

I have futzed with `lambda:InvokeFunctionURL` but this didn't make any difference

Update: I changed my `HandleLambdaRequest` function quite a bit, see below

```
func HandleLambdaEvent(ctx context.Context, request map[string]interface{}) (MyResponse, error) {
    // event
    jsonStr, err := json.Marshal(request)
    if err != nil {
        return MyResponse{Message: "can't unmarshal request"}, nil
    }
    var event Event
    if err = json.Unmarshal(jsonStr, &event); err != nil {
        return MyResponse{Message: err.Error()}, nil
    }
    if event.Name == "" {
        var apigate events.APIGatewayV2HTTPRequest
        if err = json.Unmarshal(jsonStr, &apigate); err != nil {
            return MyResponse{Message: "can't get event or request"}, nil
        }
        body := []byte(apigate.Body)
        if err = json.Unmarshal(body, &event); err != nil {
            return MyResponse{Message: "can't unmarshal api.Body"}, nil
        }
        return MyResponse{Message: fmt.Sprintf("url %s:%d", event.Name, event.Age)}, nil
    }

    return MyResponse{Message: fmt.Sprintf("invoke %s:%d", event.Name, event.Age)}, nil
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambda handles your request differently when you invoke the function through a function URL! This is not very intuitive, especially for people who are not familiar with the lambda integration in the Amazon API Gateway service, and I hope they make this more clear in the documentation. Here is the [request and response payload structures](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-invocation.html#urls-payloads). In your case, the POST payload is mapped to `event.Body`, and you need to define "body" in the "MyEvent" struct like this,

```
type MyEvent struct {
    ...
    Body string `json:body`
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Followup question: is there a way to determine which method was used? Or do I attempt one way and fall back to the other if the data is not received in that format?

Comment: @KevinDTimm You can check the `requestContext` to determine which method was used.

Comment: I don't have access to requestContext when I get a MyEvent, I actually jumped through some more hoops to try to parse a MyEvent first and if there is no data then I parse for an APIGatewayV2HTTPRequest.

I posted my method at the bottom of the question under "Update"

Answer (score 1):

`MyEvent` does not match the payload your Lambda is actually receiving.  When invoked via a Function URL, your Lambda receives an event with the shape of an [API Gateway request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-invocation.html#urls-payloads).

The [github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go@v1.36.0/events) package contains the request and response types for the various Lambda invoke events. [APIGatewayV2HTTPRequest](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go@v1.36.0/events#APIGatewayV2HTTPRequest) is the one you're looking for.  Your POST payload is in `Body`.

```golang
type APIGatewayV2HTTPRequest struct {
    Version               string                         `json:"version"`
    RouteKey              string                         `json:"routeKey"`
    RawPath               string                         `json:"rawPath"`
    RawQueryString        string                         `json:"rawQueryString"`
    Cookies               []string                       `json:"cookies,omitempty"`
    Headers               map[string]string              `json:"headers"`
    QueryStringParameters map[string]string              `json:"queryStringParameters,omitempty"`
    PathParameters        map[string]string              `json:"pathParameters,omitempty"`
    RequestContext        APIGatewayV2HTTPRequestContext `json:"requestContext"`
    StageVariables        map[string]string              `json:"stageVariables,omitempty"`
    Body                  string                         `json:"body,omitempty"`
    IsBase64Encoded       bool                           `json:"isBase64Encoded"`
}
```

Comment: the only reason you didn't get the check mark is because jellycsc answered moments before you did  :)